# Play framework - How to set cache timeout in conf file

Tags: caching, playframework, playframework-2.6

I'm working on an app using Play framework 2.6. (launched using sbt, if that matters)
I would like to set cache timeouts to a certain limit using configuration, rather than individually for each endpoint.

The old version seems to have had something like this - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.3/configuration#http

But this doesn't work for my current project. Any pointers?

(Running the app in production mode on my local sets it to:
    **Cache-Control: max-age=0**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, create your own Adapter Pattern around the Cache API:

```
package caching

import javax.inject._
import play.api.Configuration
import play.api.cache.AsyncCacheApi

import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

@Singleton
class ConfigCache @Inject()(config: Configuration, cache: AsyncCacheApi) {
  def set(name: String, obj: Any) = {
    cache.set(name, obj, config.get[Duration]("my.play.duration"))
  }
}
```

Now that you have a `ConfigCache` class you can inject that where needed...

```
package controllers

import javax.inject._
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import services.Counter
import caching.ConfigCache
import models.Account

@Singleton
class SomeController @Inject() (configCache: ConfigCache, cc: ControllerComponents)(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) extends AbstractController(cc) {

  def myAction = Action {
    configCache.set("my.item", Account(1, "bob@stackoverflow.com", 
                    "Bob", "Bobberson", "pass"))
    Ok("Yay")
  }
}
```

Try it out. Not exact code. I just put some code together without checking. I would say don't use the word 'cache' as a package as I think that's a reserved package name. Let us know how it goes and what your final answer is. ;)